# Javascript onClick get element

Tags: javascript

I want to have multiple elements calling one function with onClick, is there anyway to get what element called it though?

I thought about giving each on an id and doing function(1) and then doing it based of that but is there anyway to dynamically do this?

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: pls show us what you have tried. it helps us see what you did, and prove you did some research.

Comment: @jndne, it appears that you've got a trend of downvoted questions due to not putting forth enough effort in asking and showing [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). If you don't change your approach, you're going to find yourself question banned.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do it :

## The easy way

Use jQuery, it's a JS library which will be really usefull for everything, and it's really easy to learn because it is JS.

You'll be able to do `$(".myClass").click(function(){ // Code... });`to select all elements with the myClass class (It uses CSS selectors).

## The pure JS

Get the elements by tag, then you'll get an array and for each element in the array test if they have a certain class (give a special class to the elements you want to select).
If they have the class, apply the `addEventListener`.

:)